# Is it possible to put a Steam game onto a USB drive and have it work without a direct way to install Steam?

Tags: steam

At my school programing class, our teacher encouraged us to gather other types of video game design software to allow us to make more complex games, instead of just the base Greenfoot and Bluejay games. I remembered I had RPG Maker VX Ace on my computer at home, so now I am stuck at how I would get it to school, seeing that the county blocks Steam (and everything else good on the internet (besides this site)).

Is there a way I could get it onto a USB drive and use it on the other computer without a direct way (from the school computer) to download Steam?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I play Steam games without running Steam in the background?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/26426/can-i-play-steam-games-without-running-steam-in-the-background)

Comment: That only applies if it is impossible to get Steam onto a USB drive (not installer). If I can get both onto a USB drive, then run it and get it work, that would be fine.

Comment: I don't feel like this is a duplicate. That question pertains to running the game without running Steam on a machine where Steam is present. This question has entirely different circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

Almost all Steam games and applications are protected by Steam's copy protection scheme which requires that the Steam client be installed on the computer you use it on. It also requires that the client be able to connect to the Steam servers at least once to validate the game. RPG Maker VX Ace isn't exception, so no, you can't do what you're asking.

However there are a couple of possible workarounds. The first is that while the RPG Maker VX Ace application is protected by Steam DRM, games that you create with it aren't. So you can create your games at home and bring the finished result to to class to demonstrate. The second possibility is you might be able to [download the RPG Make VX Ace trial](http://www.rpgmakerweb.com/download/free-trials/trial-rpg-maker-vx-ace) directly from the RPG Maker web site. It's possible though that this also is protected by Steam or some other form of DRM, but it doesn't look like it from the description. Either way it doesn't cost you anything to find out.

(It's also possible that the full version of the application available direct from the web site isn't DRM protected, but this is much more costly to verify.)

Finally since you need access to the Steam servers for legitimate school work, there's a small outside chance you may be able to convince the powers-that-be to make an exception for you.

Comment: The powers-that-be would never do that (they have yet to unblock our own schools Robotics Team website). Lastly, is there a way to get Steam fully onto a USB drive (not installer) and have RPG Maker VX Ace installed onto the steam I put onto said USB drive, and run it in offline mode? Edit: County also blocked the RPG Maker VC Ace trial link you put up :|.

Comment: @Shadow No, as I said it's not possible. You need to have Steam installed on the computer you want to run it on. A USB drive is not a computer. Try downloading the the trial at home, copying it to a USB stick and then installing it at school.

Comment: I don't see how installing Steam on a usb drive won't work. The problem might be running Steam on the other computer that might have missing dlls and what not.

Comment: @Jonathan Try it then. It won't work. When you run the Steam client executable you've "installed" on the USB stick on another machine without the Steam client installed it will act as if it has never been installed on that machine. It will connect to the Internet to try to download the latest version of the Steam client. It also won't think any Steam account is logged in, so if you somehow bypass the client install, it won't let you play any games until you connect to the Internet and log on. It it didn't work this way Steam DRM would be completely useless.

Comment: So it seems to be impossible, unless I can move my desktop or other type of computer to school?

Comment: @Shadow Try downloading the free trial version at home and bringing that to school. Since it's free, it's less likely to be protected by any sort of DRM.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using a phone as a mobile hotspot - set it all up with a USB, etc. then go to school, connect the computer to your phone's mobile hotspot, and then start Steam. Once it's all loaded, close steam, turn off mobile hotspot and start steam again. Because it's done it's first verification, it should work from then on. OR you could try to get Steam to connect through a VPN, but that might be harder.

Answer (score -2):

Portable hard drive running all of steams files from there. It will require the computer hove have things already on it like .net c++ directx ect for the game to run but u can download all that even the .dll files