# Run a Steam game without steam?

Tags: steam

I might have a bit of a special situation. I have a productivity tool I bought via Steam  (Displayfusion). This helps me organize Windows on a big screen way better than Win10 or Win11.

It works fine and I am happy with it on my personal Desktop. Installed it the usual way using steam.

Now I want to use this also on my company-laptop. I have full admin access to that laptop, I simply don't want to install Steam on that machine. Having a steam - process running simply could cause questions.

So is there a way to install the Screentool without having Steam installed? It is fine by me if the tool contacts steam servers to check for license, I just do not want to have any Steam application running.

Comment: _Maybe_ a duplicate https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/26426/can-i-play-steam-games-without-running-steam-in-the-background/26460#26460 though it may need an updated answer.

Comment: Ask the company to buy you a license and install it without using Steam.

Answer (score 3):

Different for each software you can get through Steam and similar platforms.

If you bought Displayfusion on steam you need to firstly install steam, log in, install the application through Steam and after that you can just use it without needing Steam.

However as some one who works in IT, i got to say that if you install something on a company PC you should always let your IT department check it first if it is allowed by your companies ruleset. Because if you are afraid people are going to ask questions, you kinda already know what you are doing is probably wrong.

Comment: For nuance: "you kind of already anticipate that someone might interpret it as wrong", as there is nothing inherently wrong about having Steam installed. But communication is key anyway, +1.

Comment: @Joachim depends on what you work for, i spend 3 years in military Aviation, and now working in the nuclear industry as IT... if i installed steam on a work PC at either? i would not only get fired but would have ended up in a courtroom.

Comment: But I assume that is contractually established? For the record, I hadn't anticipated this to be about work in military aviation or the nuclear industry :) (And I would still argue it isn't "wrong", but risky and possibly suspicious, but that's moving into semantics and me being pedantic.)

Comment: @Joachim rule of thumb is, a work PC is NOT your property, it is the property of the company you work at. Majority of the companies (in my country at least) come with pre-installed software or a list of downloadable software. Installing any other software should be communicated with the IT department for security reasons. I for example am a Discord fan, prefer it over Teams. But companies want teams instead of discord so they can check what is being send (corporate espionage/ Doing none work stuff under work time) now if you installed discord on the side? Big no no.

Comment: Yes, that makes a lot of sense. And I would urge the OP to communicate it as well, in any case.